# Storyboard what does the tag <animations/> mean?

Tags: ios, animation, storyboard, xcode6.3, osx-elcapitan

I have updated my mac os to El Capitan and using the Xcode version 6.3 When i open the storyboard file

> `<animations/>`

tag is getting added to all the subviews. Check the xml of storyboard.

```
<activityIndicatorView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" hidesWhenStopped="YES" animating="YES" style="whiteLarge" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="njZ-Pf-Lyb">
                            <rect key="frame" x="150" y="274" width="37" height="37"/>
                            <animations/>
                            <color key="color" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                        </activityIndicatorView>
```

So what does that tag  stands for any clue ? Can i run the same project on Yosemite with Xcode 6.3 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JustinVallely Please check the date on which both questions are posted before marking it as duplicate. It effects on my stack overflow profile.

Comment: My apologies @AnkitJain. The other one has actual answers so it's appropriate to link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you may have to wait for Xcode 7.2 release (or use the 7.2 Beta for now):

[Xcode adds a lot of <animations/> tag in my storyboard and xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909873/xcode-adds-a-lot-of-animations-tag-in-my-storyboard-and-xib-file/33404369#33404369)

Answer (score -1):

actually I faced this problem also. Luckily this tag doesn't affect the oldest OS and with the same XCode version(which is 6.3 for me).

Hope this help you.

Comment: It doesn't address the question!