# Xcode adds a lot of <animations/> tag in my storyboard and xib file

Tags: storyboard, xib, xcode7

Just wanna know if anybody has the same issue as mine: Xcode adds a lot of  tags into the storyboard I touch. I try to remove but I can't because it keep adding those tags back.

It this a bug of the new Xcode I'm using (7.0.1)?

Comment: looks like we can add animations right from the interface builder in near future?^^

Comment: Same issue here, any workarounds? I'm seeing these show up in Xcode 6.4 now.

Comment: This looks to be an El Capitan issue. This happens with Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan but not Yosemite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Xcode 7.2 Beta (7C46I) released on 10/28/2015, just like these tags were added automatically when opening a Storyboard or XIB file in Xcode 7 or 7.1 on El Capitan, these tags are now being removed automatically by just opening a Storyboard or XIB file. (It now seems that the addition of the  tags may have been unintentional.)

As this has caused some issues with modifications to Storyboard and XIB files within some of my teams I recommend that if you're working with multiple people on a project that you a) coordinate to all use the same version of Xcode and b) coordinate a time to switch from Xcode 7.1 to 7.2 to avoid unnecessary merge conflicts.

*XIB file showing these tags removed after opening with Xcode 7.2 beta:*
[image: XIB file showing these tags removed after opening with Xcode 7.2 beta.]

Comment: Its probably an issue with El Capitan, i am observing the same behaviour in XCode 6.4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to be fixed on Xcode 7.2 live version (released Dec 8 2015)

Comment: I'm still getting these in `Version 7.2 (7C68)`