# Xcode XIB files has <animation> tags

Tags: xcode

Why xcode automatically adds animation tags in my xib files? 
Is animation already implemented in xib files or this is a preparation for a new feature?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode adds a lot of <animations/> tag in my storyboard and xib file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909873/xcode-adds-a-lot-of-animations-tag-in-my-storyboard-and-xib-file)

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of Xcode seem to add these in automatically. If you look in the Core Animation inspector (the rightmost tab of the inspector), you can adjust the animation properties of a view.